# What does 'skip session storage' in Devise gem mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am reading Devise gem's initializer file (config/initializers/deviser.rb) and having a hard time comprehending this part.

```
# By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
# :http_auth and :token_auth by adding those symbols to the array below.
# Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
# may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
# passing :skip => :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb

config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
```

The reason I'm looking at this is because I'm trying to use api based token authentication, in which case I need to change that config line to:

```
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :token_auth]
```

Can anyone explain what the comments are saying?

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply, it tells Devise not to store the user in the session. Here's another explanation for it:

skip_session_storage+: By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for http and token auth by appending values to array: :skip_session_storage => [:token_auth] or :skip_session_storage => [:http_auth, :token_auth],by default is set to skip_session_storage => [:http_auth].

[Devise::Models::Authenticatable](http://test.calder.org/gems/doc/devise-2.1.2/rdoc/Devise/Models/Authenticatable.html)

For your intents and purposes, I would disable session caching using Warden/Devise; I believe it's interfered with certain APIs (don't take my word for it though). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
# may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
# passing :skip => :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
```

This part tells you that if you disable the use of sessions for all authentication methods like in the following line:

```
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :token_auth]
```

then you don't need the routes to the sessions automatically generated by `devise_for` by defaults.
So you should add the following in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => :sessions
```

Hope it helps a bit.